# Why does restricting `ssm:sendCommand` to a specific document via an IAM policy show access denied?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ssm

I'm trying to have an IAM user who can only use SSM Run Command with a specific Document.

If I have the following policy attached to the user, that user can indeed only successfully execute `AWS-RunShellScript` (which is an AWS managed) document on EC2 instances.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeDocument",
                "ssm:DescribeDocumentParameters",
                "ssm:DescribeDocumentPermission",
                "ssm:GetCommandInvocation",
                "ssm:GetDocument",
                "ssm:ListCommandInvocations",
                "ssm:ListCommands",
                "ssm:ListDocumentMetadataHistory",
                "ssm:ListDocuments",
                "ssm:ListDocumentVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ssm:SendCommand",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/AWS-RunShellScript"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I replace the resource item in the policy with a custom document ARN that I created (e.g. `arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/CustomDocument`), I get "Access Denied"

[image]

Comment: Try adding the EC2 instances running the document to the policy too e.g. `"Resource": [..., "arn:aws:ec2:*:999999999999:instance/*"]`. Does that work?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary that was it! Apparently instance isn't optional, despite what the docs claim ‍♂️ Thanks. If you post this as an answer, I can award you the bounty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really clear in the documentation but to limit `ssm:SendCommand`, you must use the `Resource` field to **specify both what document(s) the IAM user is allowed to run *and* what instance(s) you allow commands to be run on**.

The user would see all instances when trying to run a command but will only be able to execute commands for the EC2 instance IDs specified in the IAM policy.

You can specify the policy to allow any instance like below if needs be or specify a limited list of instance IDs in line with the standard security advice of granting [least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) in IAM policies.

As to why the AWS managed document works, it's probably some internal magic ‍♂️

This should work:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"ssm:SendCommand",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:999999999999:instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/AWS-RunShellScript"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly similar unexpected behaviour (not really clear in the documentation either): if you define 2 blocks for the same action, they are considered by AWS as just one, eg:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"ssm:SendCommand",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:999999999999:instance/i-1",
            "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/AWS-RunShellScript"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"ssm:SendCommand",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:999999999999:instance/i-2",
            "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/AWS-SecondDoc"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

will allow you to connect to i-1 with both "AWS-RunShellScript" and "AWS-SecondDoc" (and same for i-2).

Answer (score 0):

For the below ARN used, remove the account id.
arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:999999999999:document/AWS-RunShellScript

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).